# Angular.js validation. Programatically set form fields properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set up a form validation systems with angular as follows.

An error class is assigned when the field is both $invalid && $dirty.

This works great for individual fields. Here is an example field.

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="getErrorClasses(schoolSignup.first_name)">
      <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
       <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="first_name" name="first_name" required ng-maxlength="30" ng-model="school.first_name">
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="showError(schoolSignup.first_name, 'required')">This field is required</span>
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="showError(schoolSignup.first_name, 'maxlength')">Maximum of 30 character allowed</span>
        </div>
   </div>
```

`schoolSignup` is the name of the form.

`ng-class="getErrorClasses(schoolSignup.first_name)">` is defined in the controller as

```
$scope.getErrorClasses = function(ngModelContoller) {
        return {
            error: ngModelContoller.$invalid && ngModelContoller.$dirty
        };
    };
```

And on the error help items `ng-show="showError(schoolSignup.first_name, 'required')"` is defined as:

```
$scope.showError = function(ngModelController, error) {
      return ngModelController.$dirty && ngModelController.$error[error];
  };
```

This all works fine.

However, what I want to do is make it so if the user clicks the submit button and all the individual fields that are required are invalid then show the `required` error message next to the appropriate fields.

This will require setting all the individual fields to `$dirty` and the `$error['required']` value to `true` based on this system.

I have set up a directive on the submit button called `can-save` as follows which has access to the form.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" can-save="schoolSignup">Register</button>
```

-

```
.directive('canSave', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var form = scope.$eval(attrs.canSave);

        var valid = false;

        element.click(function(){
            if(!valid)
            {
                // show errors

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });

        scope.$watch(function() {
            return form.$dirty && form.$valid;
        }, function(value) {
            valid = !!value;
        });
    }

});
```

This all works except for making the errors show as desired.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I've amended my directive to loop through the errors and set each to `$dirty` and then run `$rootScope.$digest()`:

```
.directive('canSave', function ($rootScope) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var form = scope.$eval(attrs.canSave);

        element.click(function () {
            if(form.$dirty && form.$valid) {
                return true;
            } else {
                // show errors
                angular.forEach(form.$error, function (value, key) {
                    var type = form.$error[key];

                    angular.forEach(type, function (item) {
                        item.$dirty = true;
                        item.$pristine = false;
                    });
                });

                $rootScope.$digest();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```